# Return date in French

Tags: date

```
$current_post['date'] = get_the_date( $smof_data['blog-date_format'] );
echo $current_post['date'];
```

I would like to display the date in french.
How can I do that using de code above?

Comment: You better ask this question to the SMOF developers. It's off-topic here.

Comment: what is SMOF ? Single-mode optical fiber ?

Comment: Looks like the options are coming from Slightly Modified Options Framework which is off-topic here, but perhaps the question could be answered if that part is removed (by editing the question) and details about how the date should be formatted are added too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonjour :)

you can use the function `date_i18n`, e.g. like this

```
        $dateToDisplay = time();

        echo date_i18n(get_option("date_format"), $dateToDisplay);
```

look in the codex for more informations
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n